# Generic inheritance in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, type-inference

I'm trying to implement a few structures from Okasaki's book in Scala, and in tests try to keep the actual tests in the base class, only using subclasses to provide the instance-under-test.

For example, a test for unbalanced (tree) set looks as follows:

```
class UnbalancedSetSpec
  extends SetSpec(new UnbalancedSet[Int])
  with IntElements
```

where

```
abstract class SetSpec[E, S](val set: Set[E, S]) extends Specification with ScalaCheck {

  implicit def elements: Arbitrary[E]

  // ...

  private def setFrom(es: Seq[E]): S = es.foldRight(set.empty)(set.insert)
}
```

Now sometimes I want to specialise the child spec, e.g.

```
class RedBlackSetSpec
  extends SetSpec(new RedBlackSet[Int])
  with IntElements {

  "fromOrdList" should {
    "be balanced" ! prop { (a: List[Int]) =>
      val s = RedBlackSet.fromOrdList(a.sorted)

      set.isValid(s) should beTrue
    }
  }
}
```

it fails because there's no method `isValid` on `Set[E, S]` — it's defined in `RedBlackSet[E]`. But if I go ahead and change `SetSpec[E, S](val set: Set[E, S])` to `SetSpec[E, S, SES <: Set[E, S]](val set: SES)`, this particular problem disappears, but the code still fails to compile:

```
Error:(7, 11) inferred type arguments [Nothing,Nothing,okasaki.RedBlackSet[Int]] do not conform to class SetSpec's type parameter bounds [E,S,SES <: okasaki.Set[E,S]]
  extends SetSpec(new RedBlackSet[Int])
          ^

Error:(7, 11) inferred type arguments [Nothing,Nothing,okasaki.UnbalancedSet[Int]] do not conform to class SetSpec's type parameter bounds [E,S,SES <: okasaki.Set[E,S]]
  extends SetSpec(new UnbalancedSet[Int])
          ^
```

The definition of `RedBlackSet` is as follows:

```
package okasaki

class RedBlackSet[E](implicit ord: Ordering[E]) extends Set[E, RBTree[E]] {
```

so I would expect `E` to be inferred as `Int` rather than `Nothing`, and `S` as `RBTree[Int]` — but it doesn't happen.

```
class RedBlackSetSpec
  extends SetSpec[Int, RedBlackSet.RBTree[Int], RedBlackSet[Int]](new RedBlackSet[Int])
  with IntElements {
```

and

```
class UnbalancedSetSpec
  extends SetSpec[Int, BinaryTree[Int], UnbalancedSet[Int]](new UnbalancedSet[Int])
  with IntElements
```

work fine, but look ugly.

I'm struggling to understand why `E` and `S` are not inferred here. Any hints?

Comment: What is the variance of the type parameters of `okasaki.Set[E, S]`?

Comment: Good question! `Set[E, S]` itself is invariant;  `RBTree[+E]` is covariant (to allow for `object Empty extends RBTree[Nothing]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a well-known problem with Scala type inference: it can't infer `SES` "first" and use it to infer `E` and `S`. One solution comes to mind:

```
class RedBlackSetSpec(override val set: RedBlackSet[Int]) extends SetSpec(set) with IntElements {
  def this() = this(new RedBlackSet[Int])
  ...
}
```

It becomes less ugly if you make `set` in `SetSpec` an abstract `val` instead of a constructor argument, but with a slight tradeoff in cases you *don't* need to specialize. I think there should be a better one, but this should work.